# Can I Update Subscription Properties via REST API using PATCH method?

Tags: office365api, outlook-restapi, office365-restapi

I know that when you want to renew your subscription I need to call subscriptions endpoint with payload which tells new expiration date or nothing, to get maximum 3 days.

```
// endpoint
me/subscriptions($subscriptionId)

// payload
{
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.OutlookServices.PushSubscription"
}
```

What I want to do now, is to update NotificationURL property of that subscription.

I figured it should work like this using PATCH method:

```
// endpoint
me/subscriptions($subscriptionId)

// payload
{
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.OutlookServices.PushSubscription",
    "NotificationURL": "https://app.domain.com/notifications"
}
```

But when I try to do this I only get following errors:

- **code:** ErrorInvalidParameter
- **message:** Notification URL 'https://oldapp.domain.com/notifications?validationtoken=[someHashCode]' verification failed 'System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

Well, of course it fails and gives 404, because it's trying to connect old NotificationURL. It looks like, it's just trying to renew subcription instead of only updating NotificationURL property of that subscription.

I know I can handle this manually in few ways for example by creating new subscriptions, but I want to make this to work automatically everytime my server boots. And it feels like a good idea to just update the NotificationURL instead of unsubscribing from all notificaitons and creating new ones.

Any help would be appreciated!